# Node.js: Viewing string variable in my browser

Tags: html, node.js, string

So lets say I have a file called string.js, it might look something like this:

```
var hello = "Hello World!";
```

And lets say I have a file called hello.html.

How do I now view that string upon opening hello.html in my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task can be divided into two parts:

1.add javascript codes to html and control then content

2.use node.js server to serve the html file up

The first task is pretty straightforward. You just have to include the .js file in your html. This is basic html-javascript application. You can find a lot of resource to learn it. W3schools is a very good site for beginners.

You have several ways to do task 2. Your objective is serve static contents. Let's use Hapi framework as an example.

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });
server.register(require('inert'), (err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/sample',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply.file('/your html file');
        }
    });
});
server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

Now, once you enter localhost:3000/sample in your browser, you will be able to see the result.

In the code, what you did is creating a Hapi server and setting a route. The route replies you a html file once it is called.

Comment: This is one way to do it, though not how I eventually implemented. This is the most correct answer so take my correct answer check!

Answer (score 0):

Node.js runs server side. To be able to display Hello world, you would need to do something like:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('Hello World');
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: This method is for checking localhost:3000, not an actual webpage, right? There has to be some way I can get the string in node.js to an html file, right?

Comment: I think you mean Javascript and not Node? Check out [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/)